# Missing ecto_image_pipeline

Tags: ros, object-recognition

I am trying to run object recognition kitchen adn to do mesh_object but when I run

```
rosrun object_recognition_reconstruction mesh_object --all --visualize --commit
```

I get this:

```
import ecto_image_pipeline.conversion
ImportError: No module named conversion
```

I found somewhere that I have to add the ecto_image_pipeline ros package to my local workspace and build the module by hand but I don't know how to do it. Can anyone help me please?

Comment: Check out the [ROS tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials). Steps 1-4 should be sufficient.

Comment: I reinstalled ORK and it works now.